# Can I change workflow start options, once workflow is created?

Tags: 2007, workflow

I am using MOSS 2007.  I created a simple workflow that works but now want to add the option to automatically start it if an item is changed but don't see how to do that?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

From the list/library toolbar click into the List or Library Settings, choose Workflow Settings underneath the Permissions and Management section and then you should see your workflow name there.

From there click your workflow name and you will get the Change a Workflow form that allows you to modify start options.

hth